# I am trying to retrieive data from two tables SQL Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables tbl_inc t and tbl_expn.
All fields of two tables are same except its primary key
I want to get the amount to display a chart for a month in an year with sum(t.amount) and sum(d.amount) for each day.
I have multiple amount in a single day.
The following code do not adds up the amount for each day

```
select extract(day from t.date_id) as tday,
extract(month from t.date_id) as mon,
extract(year from t.date_id) as yr,
t.amount as incamt,
d.amount as expamt 
from tbl_inc t,tbl_expn d 
where t.user_id=d.user_id and 
t.user_id='222' and 
extract(month from t.date_id)='04' and 
extract(month from d.date_id)='04' and 
extract(year from t.date_id)='2015' and 
extract(year from d.date_id)='2015' and 
extract(day from t.date_id)=extract(day from d.date_id) 
order by t.date_id
```

The result for this code is this

```
TDAY    MON YR      INCAMT  EXPAMT
29      4   2015    50      600
29      4   2015    100     200
29      4   2015    50      200
29      4   2015    100     600
30      4   2015    70      700
30      4   2015    30      500
30      4   2015    70      700
30      4   2015    30      500
```

I want the output as

```
TDAY    MON YR      INCAMT  EXPAMT
29      4   2015    150     800
30      4   2015    100     1200
```

please help...

Comment: if you use oracle, why do you flag it sql server?

Comment: Can you modify this code using JOIN .I don't know how to do that :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your date_id is without time part, you can drop the `trunc`. the `trunc` drops the timepart if it would be there.

you select just one month, grouping and selecting the dateparts year and month seams useless since you already know them.

```
select extract(day from t.date_id) as tday
     , ta as incamt
     , da as expamt 
     , t.*, d.*

from ( select trunc(date_id) date_id, user_id, sum(amount) ta from t group by trunc(date_id), user_id ) t
   , ( select trunc(date_id) date_id, user_id, sum(amount) da from d group by trunc(date_id), user_id ) d
where t.user_id = d.user_id 
  and t.date_id = d.date_id

  and t.user_id=1
  and extract(month from t.date_id)='04'
  and extract(year  from t.date_id)='2015'

order by extract(day from t.date_id)
```

you did not write anything about the count of rows you have but you'll need an index on both tables. i suggest `user_id, extract(month from date_id), extract(year from date_id)` on one and `user_id, trunc(date_id)` on the other

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83efc/6

Comment: I am not getting the output as required.
If there are two amount for each table then the out put is doubled
If there are three then its thrice

Only works for single amount in that day

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a `SUM` and `GROUP BY` Give this a try:

```
select 
    extract(day from t.date_id) as tday,
    extract(month from t.date_id) as mon,
    extract(year from t.date_id) as yr,
    SUM(t.amount) as incamt,
    SUM(d.amount) as expamt 
from tbl_inc t,tbl_expn d 
where t.user_id=d.user_id and 
    t.user_id='222' and 
    extract(month from t.date_id)='04' and 
    extract(month from d.date_id)='04' and 
    extract(year from t.date_id)='2015' and 
    extract(year from d.date_id)='2015' and 
    extract(day from t.date_id)=extract(day from d.date_id) 
GROUP BY extract(day from t.date_id), extract(month from t.date_id), extract(year from t.date_id)
order by t.date_id
```

You will also want change your `from tbl_inc t,tbl_expn d` to a proper `JOIN` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Is showing up ! :-(